# Shopify: redirect sharing links

Tags: store, shopify

i use S Loyalty. I followed all the instructions for setting up but faced the problem of redirecting

link will be  `http://"YOUR STORE DOMAIN"/#!sharing/`
but when I try to link - i have `http://"YOUR STORE DOMAIN"/#/!sharing/`

(added '/')
and nothing happens

Maybe someone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use angular.js -> need to add

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!sharing');
```